# Return value with different formatting / styling on result of conditional - excel

Tags: excel, conditional-statements

Im trying to write a conditional to see if any cells have more than 70 characters in them (including spaces), using `len()` then if the results are > 70 chars i want to make the output red and bold.

I understand how to do this with php or js, but im a little unsure when it comes to excel syntax.

So far ive got

```
=If(len(a1) > 70, //len() styled red and bold)
```

Answer (score 0):

As a conditional formatting (formula) rule you just need

```
=LEN(A1)>70
```

This expression is either True or False, if it is True it applies the formatting.